# Account Deletion Secure Storage Flutter

Tags: android, json, flutter, firebase, api

I want to delete user in my flutter app. I am a bit confused with the API call using secure storage. Can you help me out with the code?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you mean flutter secure storage

```
static final _storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
static Future deleteAuthAll() async => await _storage.deleteAll();// delete all
static Future deleteAuth(String key) async => await _storage.delete(key: key);//delete specific key
```